# Passing variable from success call in service through controller to view

Tags: angularjs, service, scope, call

In my ui-bootstrap modal I have 3 `modal-body` div's.

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-show="$ctrl.selected.item == 'registration'">...</div>
<div class="modal-body" ng-show="$ctrl.selected.item == 'thanks'">...</div>
<div class="modal-body" ng-show="$ctrl.selected.item == 'error'">...</div>
```

By changing `$ctrl.selected.item` I change HTML inside my modal window. Now I need to change this variable(property of object indeed) inside a registerService which is injected do registerwindow' controller.

```
app.service('registerService', ['$http', 'localStorageService', function ($http, localStorageService) {
this.registerUser = function (registerInfo) {

    $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/v1/sign_up',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: registerInfo.email,
            nick: registerInfo.nick,
            password: registerInfo.password,
            password_confirmation: registerInfo.password_confirmation
        }
    })

    .then(function successCall(response) {
        console.log('user added'); // delete it
        $ctrl.selected.item = $ctrl.items[1];

    }, function errorCall(respone) {
        console.log('error callback register ');
        console.log(respone.data);
        $ctrl.selected.item = $ctrl.items[2];
    })


};
}]);
```

This approach with `$ctrl.selected.item = $ctrl.items[1];` doesn't work obviously.. How can I do this? I have no clue I need to do this asynchronously.

Comment: Maybe I can create factory which will do same job ass localStorageService but asynchronously inject this factory to register service and on success call set async this object property? Factory would be something like this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1b8756bf7ef78b189b414940d53442a1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use Angular's `$q` service to handle this. The service's method would look like this:

```
this.registerUser = function (registerInfo) {

var deferred = $q.defer();

$http({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/v1/sign_up',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        email: registerInfo.email,
        nick: registerInfo.nick,
        password: registerInfo.password,
        password_confirmation: registerInfo.password_confirmation
    }
})

.then(function successCall(response) {
    console.log('user added'); // delete it
    //$ctrl.selected.item = $ctrl.items[1];
    deferred.resolve(); //Resolve the promise - success
}, function errorCall(respone) {
    console.log('error callback register ');
    console.log(respone.data);
    //$ctrl.selected.item = $ctrl.items[2];
    deferred.reject(); //Reject the promise - failure
});

return deferred.promise;
};
```

*Remember to inject $q into your service!*

Within your controller, you'd call your service method like so, then adjust the scope variable within the `.then` and `.catch`:

```
registerService.registerUser(registerInfo)
   .then(function() {
       $scope.selected.item = $scope.items[1];
       //Not sure what your controller looks like, you may be using controllerAs, so this will be a bit different
   })
   .catch(function() {
       $scope.selected.item = $scope.items[2];
   });
```

Comment: what about my solution is it good? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1b8756bf7ef78b189b414940d53442a1 i would need async local storage anyway so maybe its better approach for me?